# How to make a curved Cone?

Tags: mesh

I'm making a model for a thing (don't really know how to describe it) and i'm trying to make some curved cones so as to replicate the shape of the floating horns on the character.
anyone have any ideas?

i'm also using 2.8 and am extremely new, so please try to dumb it down.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by adding a cone to your scene: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select *Mesh ► Cone*. Next press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go into Edit Mode then press <kbd>NUM PAD 5</kbd> for top view.

[image: Top View Edge Select Mode]

Note the three buttons in the red box in the screenshot. These are the three mesh selection modes in blender. The left one is Vertex Select, the center one (highlighted in green) is Edge Select, and the right one is Face Select.

Here is a better view.

[image: Edge Select Mode Closeup]

Now you will want to click on Edge Mode (the center one). Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all and then <kbd>C</kbd> to enter brush select mode and click on the top (center) of the cone. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave brush select mode and right click to bring up the *Edge Context Menu*.

[image: Edge Context Menu > Subdivide]

Click on *Subdivide*. Now open the box in the lower right hand corner that says 'Subdivide' if it is not already open. Your project should look like this:

[image: Subdivide Settings]

Set the Number of Cuts to 12, then click on Vertex Select Mode as discussed above. Press <kbd>NUM PAD 1</kbd> to enter front view and click on the highest point of the cone.

[image: Proportional Editing Menu]

Now enable Proportional Editing by clicking the button below the pop-up menu in the screenshot that looks like a target. Click the button to the right of the target and select Sharp from the pop-up menu (you can experiment with other modes later for different effects). Now press the following keys in order: <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now at this point the cone looks silly I know, but we'll fix that.

[image: Move menu > Proportional Size]

In the lower right corner the box is now labeled Move. Increase the Proportional Size value till the cone has a nice curve. I used a value of 2.23. At this point you can play with the Proportional Falloff to see what the other effects do. Below to the left is linear falloff and to the right is inverse square falloff. The center one is sharp falloff as we just made.

[image: Falloff Mode Demos]

I hope this tutorial helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Or do it with bezier curves and the bevel object. The radiuses are, from top, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1. Convert to mesh when done. Radiuses are given in the menu that appears after hitting N in the 3D viewport.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My go-to would just be extruding (E) an edge ring (ring of vertices, you can get one from adding a circle mesh) upwards, scaling it down (S), rotating if I needed (R), repeating this, and at the final point merge vertices (Alt+M "At Center"? I have it bound to .)

Comment: That's a harder way to do it than Proportional Editing and the result would be pretty rough. Also it's good to use <kbd>{button}</kbd> formatting for shortcuts :)

Comment: Result is only as rough as you make it, as long as you have a good eye it works fine.