# How to make this stylish «cutting mat» theme?

Tags: theme

[image: unknown theme source]

Hello to everyone! I found this image in one of the topics called «[How to make a curved Cone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153579/118992)».

Is this a *«cutting mat»* theme? Where can i find it? Thanks!

Comment: looks like a simple grid...

Comment: You can ask the post author (Lukasz-40sth), he seems quite active. I don't know the best way to contact an user, maybe tag him here, or ask in a comment under his answer.

Comment: @Luciano yes, it's just a grid, and I'm wondering how you can make it the same color

Comment: @thibsert I know, for 40 minutes I was looking for ways to contact, but I just do not have enough reputation - it requires as much as 50! I didn't have an account here before, I had to register to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the grid color here:

[image]

and background here:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the instruction, but I asked more about the theme file, not the colors that I can copy with some kind of eyedropper tool